# $y=\sqrt x \rightarrow \ln y = \ln x$ problem

Tags: data-analysis

So I had some raw data, and it looked like there was a square root relation.
I plotted graphs of $y=\sqrt{x}$

[image]

They look kind of straight. So doing the algebra and taking the ln of both sides, we get $\ln y=0.5 \ln x+\ln k$

I then plotted the graphs of the ln values, but they weren't that straight. Clearly, there is a problem here. What exactly can be done about it?

[image]

Comment: Did you have a particularly reason to think it should be a square-root relation? In general, I find it's a bad idea to 'guess' a functional form empirically. (On the other hand, guessing from _theory_ is usually a good idea.)

Comment: @Semiclassical there's actually not a lot of quantitative theory available but from what I have found, the relation is a square root one. My raw data looks like it too..

Comment: Hmm. Certainly there's a small but obvious deviation from square-root behavior. But the presence of that deviation is all the math can really say. The "_why_" of it is something to do with the model or the experimental conditions, i.e. the context of the data. We can't really help with that.